# Can I select last, first row of GROUP BY query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select, gaps-and-islands

[Using MySQL]
There is a table messages that contains data as shown below:

```
Id   Name   Other_Columns
-------------------------
1    A       A1
2    A       A2
3    A       A3
4    B       B1
5    B       B2
6    C       C1
7    A       A4
8    A       A5
```

What query will return the following result?

```
1    A       (A3 - A1)
4    B       (B2 - B1)
6    C       (C1 - C1)
7    A       (A5 - A4)
```

Comment: The output of "other columns" is confusing in the result. Do you want to display a range? Subtraction? Something else?

Comment: Also, do you want to select first and last? or first? or last? the title is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Bottom_one.Id,Bottom_one.Name ,Bottom_one.Other_Columns

FROM `T1` as Top_one

Right JOIN T1 AS Bottom_one
ON Top_one.Id = Bottom_one.Id - 1

WHERE Top_one.Name IS NULL OR Top_one.Name != Bottom_one.Name
```

Gives a close result:

```
Id  Name    Other_Columns
1   A       A1
4   B       B1
6   C       C1
7   A       A4
```

And this :

```
SELECT Top_one.Id,Top_one.Name ,Top_one.Other_Columns

FROM `T1` as Top_one

Left JOIN T1 AS Bottom_one
ON Top_one.Id = Bottom_one.Id - 1

WHERE Bottom_one.Name IS NULL OR Top_one.Name != Bottom_one.Name
```

gives the other limits in Other_Columns

```
Id  Name    Other_Columns
3   A       A3
5   B       B2
6   C       C1
8   A       A5
```

I have no idea how to combine them into one SQL statement. (Of course it's trivial to do programmatically)

Here's a table dump if anybody else wants to play with it.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `T1` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Other_Columns` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`Id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;

INSERT INTO `T1` (`Id`, `Name`, `Other_Columns`) VALUES
(1, 'A', 'A1'),
(2, 'A', 'A2'),
(3, 'A', 'A3'),
(4, 'B', 'B1'),
(5, 'B', 'B2'),
(6, 'C', 'C1'),
(7, 'A', 'A4'),
(8, 'A', 'A5');
```

Nice Puzzle!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select min(ID) as FirstId,Name,
       Concat(max(Other_columns),"-",min(Other_Columns)) as Ans
from msgtable
group by Name
```

Comment: Ah just seen the problem with this. The desired results has two `A` rows. The OP needs a gaps and islands type query.

Comment: Good catch Martin.   Looked like a simple group by and concat, but that last A makes it a bit more involved...